# Getting error of scriptcs when trying to run C# code in VS Code in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code

[Running] scriptcs "/home/yash/netcore/netcore/Program.cs"
/bin/sh: 1: scriptcs: not found

[Done] exited with code=127 in 0.012 seconds

Comment: open folder with `ProjectName.csproj` and type `dotnet run`.
Also you can configure tasks for build and run. Press F5 and VS will configure it for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install mono-complete if you want to run software for Mono or Microsoft .NET which you are not installing from a Debian package.

Then, nstall mono-complete. In all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install mono-complete
```

Save your C# code in a file called hello.cs. Example hello.cs code is:
Make hello.cs executable. Right-click the hello.cs file -> select Properties -> Permissions tab -> put a checkmark to the left of Allow executing file as program.

Change directories using the `cd` command to the directory that contains the hello.cs file.

Use the `mcs` compiler and create a Windows executable named hello.exe from the source hello.cs:

```
mcs -out:hello.exe hello.cs
```

Run the hello.exe program with mono:

```
mono hello.exe
```

The results of running your program in step 6. should be:

> Hello World!

Press Enter to exit back to a default terminal prompt.

Decompile the executable file.

```
monodis --output=decompiled-hello.txt hello.exe
```

Comment: why use mono when dotnet core is available? mono is no longer best way to develop in linux

Answer (score 0):

Your code probably is not compiling as you didn't install or set the compiler on your computer. You need to install Run Time Compile for C# and .NET Core SDK, then use the terminal to run your code. Here some instructions that could help you set this up https://almirvuk.blogspot.com/2016/09/run-and-compile-c-in-visual-studio-code.html. Otherwise, you can install Visual Studio, which will take care of its own for compiling when you Run your code.